# How to achieve this liney camcorder effect on Premiere Pro or After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, video-editor, effects, visual-effects, premiere-pro

I've been looking for a way to achieve
this effect but it doesn't seem to work accurately well.

Answer (score 2):

This is an artefact from de-[interlacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlaced_video).

You can simulate it using things like the [Bad TV](https://aescripts.com/bad-tv/) or [Holomatrix](https://www.maxon.net/en/red-giant/universe/holomatrix) plugins.

You can get some way towards it using the free Venetian Blinds plugin in After Effects (or by interlacing and de-interlacing some footage).